# Incompatibility between Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions and xunit.runner.visualstudio

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, xunit, visual-studio-2019

I have a Azure Functions v2 library I'm working on with unit tests written using xunit 2.4.1. I seem to be having a conflict between Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.29 and xunit.runner.visualstudio 2.4.1.

The problem is that when the unit test project references Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions, the **build output path changes** to include an extra `bin\` folder in it:

Without the reference to Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions, the output assembly is in:

```
bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\unittests.dll
```

Once I add the reference to Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions, the output assembly is in (relative to the project folder):

```
bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\bin\UnitTests.dll
```

Unfortunately, the test runner seems to always look for the unit test assembly at `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\UnitTests.dll`, as indicated by the error message:

```
Could not find file UnitTests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\UnitTests.dll.
```

I've tried the following, none of which fixed the problem:

- Changing the target framework between 2.1, 2.2 and 3.0. This made no different
- Specifying an output path in the project settings. The extraneous `bin` folder is still added.
- Adding `<AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>` to the unit test project, but all this does is remove the netcoreapp2.1 part of the path.

**Is there anything I can do as a workaround to get the test runner to work within VS?**

If I were to report a bug, which one should I pick:

- A bug in Visual Studio (supplying the wrong binary path to the test runner)?
- A bug in the test runner (getting the wrong path to the output directory?
- A bug in the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions library (appending an unneeded path to the output folder)?

Comment: Anything different than what’s documented here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-test-a-function#c-in-visual-studio

Comment: I don't see anything in that link that talks about the problem I'm experiencing.